# Is it good practice to make a global variable always volatile?

Tags: c

I know which is the meaning of volatile. I need to ask that if my variable is global, is it good practise to make it volatile, even i dont use interface with hardware.

Header:

```
typedef struct
{
  int Value;
}Var_;
extern volatile Var_ myVariable;
```

Source:

```
volatile Var_ myVariable;
```

Comment: Why do you think doing so would be "good practise"? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: Succinctly, "No".  What on earth gave you the idea that the answer might be "Yes"?

Comment: For keeping one route in my software creation. If it doesn' influence me anywhere. I will create all my variables as volatile

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler , thank you for the answer. Can you explain me the reason, and what errors or traps can i have if i will do this?

Comment: Don't use `volatile` unless there are solid grounds for doing so.  It is not an aid to writing threaded code.  It is not something to use casually.  AFAICR, I've never needed to use it — but I've only been coding about 35 years, so maybe I've just been unlucky.  Using `volatile` makes it hard for the compiler's optimizer to optimize.  It therefore doesn't improve the performance of your program.

Comment: Why the need for global variables in the first place? You should think 3 times before using global variables.

Comment: The only reason i think that i need this is: if your variable is changed inside an interrupt. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: @ Unimportant: My project is big, and i don't want to write a source file with 2000 lines of code, so i want to create 3 source file and connecting a global variable with my source files. Correct me, if i am wrong

Comment: First, 2000 lines isn't big.  It isn't small, but it isn't big.  Second, unless your signal handler goes modifying global variables, there isn't a problem with volatility.  The C standard is incredibly restrictive about what you can do inside a signal handler; the POSIX standard is a lot less restrictive.  The POSIX rules are more representative of 'real systems'.  But even here, things are not usually volatile.  If you work with embedded systems and have memory-mapped I/O registers or the like, then `volatile` can be a help.  Routine global variables should simply not be `volatile`.

Comment: @ddd If the project is big that is all the more reason to avoid global variables - You'll just end up with a bigger mess otherwise. Besides, writing proper interface functions isn't that much work.

Comment: The good practice is to use the best tool for the proper cases. Use volatile when you want to have volatile effects (disallow optimization on that variable). Use a global variable when it is proper to use (generally, don't use global variables, cause it makes your code non-reentrant). @ddd `The only reason...` there are multiple reasons, the only reason is when an (abstract) compiler can't determine when and how will the variable change, for example when you "change" a variable from inside an "interrupt". Then you want to force all code to read from the variable.

Comment: @ Unimportant , how can i avoid global variables? With funcrions?

Comment: A point in my opinion: the size of a project is not given by the number of lines

Comment: In my option, i can handle better multiple source and header files. Thank you for your opinion

Comment: If you are writing a big code, don't use global variables and don't use volatile. It will make your code unbearable to maintain properly. Volatile will slow down your code, disallow optimizations. Write a proper object, pass handles and state variables, write access functions, an API, create an abstraction. Look at `FILE*` from standard library. Volatiles are only single small variables only those needed from inside the interrupt handler (maybe a input/output buffer and buffer position).

Comment: `how can i avoid global variables?` You can pass all variables and states and everything as arguments to functions. Compare `int global = 1; int func(void) { printf("%d", global); } int main() { func(); }` and `int func(int global){ ..} int main() { int global = 1; func(global)`

Comment: "I know which is the meaning of volatile" - sorry to tell, but if you had, you'd know the answer. Said that: you need to do research what `volatile` means and what not. Also learn about atomics.

Comment: I sometimes use 'volatile' if I want to suppress optimizations on a specific variable. Mainly if I want to look at disassemblies. But it should not stay there in production code, except for the reasons given in the other comments.

Answer (score 3):

No.  If you’re writing multi-threaded code, you want to use atomic variables, not `volatile`.  For example, many concurrent structures need to be kept consistent, not modified one word at a time.

If no other thread, process or hardware is modifying the variable, you should not use either atomics or `volatile`.  It will just complicate the program, run slower, and disable certain APIs for no reason.

The `volatile` keyword has historically been used for a few different things (such as telling the compiler not to optimize away a delay loop), but its purpose in C11 is narrow: to specify that a value in memory will change by some means that doesn’t follow the rules of atomics.  You need it to write some kinds of device drivers, but [it’s discouraged even in other low-level code such as OS kernels.](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/volatile-considered-harmful.html)

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not good practice. `volatile` informs the C implementation (largely the compiler) that an object may be changed by something outside of the C implementation or that accesses to the object within the C implementation may have desired effects outside the C implementation. As long as your global object is only used and modified inside your own program, it has no volatile effects, and declaring it with `volatile` causes the compiler to suppress optimization and to generate unnecessary accesses to it within your program.